# Recursivley copy files inside of a directory, inside of another directory.

Tags: c#, loops, directory

I'm creating a program that will create backups of my git project when I need them and am attempting to copy all the files inside of one directory, along with all the files that are inside of the directories, directories. However when I run this program, it only copies that files that are inside of the starting directory, for example I have this directory:

```
$ ls
email/
```

Inside of that directory I have these files and directories:

```
$ ls
gen_email.rb*  lib/  LICENSE.txt  log/  readme.md
```

Inside of `lib` I have

```
email/  list.yml  modules/  tools/
```

Inside of `log` I have

```
email_log.LOG
```

Now I need to be able to copy the files inside of this directory, along with the files that are inside of `lib` and `log` along with the directories and files that are inside of those.

When I run this program I get the following:

```
'06-02-2016 fl2knjas.z24'/
```

And inside of this is:

```
gen_email.rb*  LICENSE.txt  readme.md
```

So my program is doing it's job, yes but it is leaving out some of the directories and files..

Source:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace BackupGen
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Copy(string strtDir, string destDir)
        {
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(strtDir))
                File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileName(file)));

            foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(strtDir))
                Copy(directory, Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileName(directory)));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
            var fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();


            var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory($"{date} {fileName}");

            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to create a backup..");
            try
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory($@"Z:\backups\{dir}");
                Copy(@"C:\Users\git_orgin\email", $@"Z:\backups\{dir}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Backup created as {dir}");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong.. {0}", e.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Question being, how can I get this to continue running through all the directories, inside of the `strtDir` and copy over all the files?

Comment: What's wrong with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` to run the xcopy command, which can already recursively copy files?

Comment: @EricJ. : Maybe he wants to implement his own progress reporting system? :)

Comment: Great learning exercise, but if a wheel already exists, I like to point it out :-)

Comment: @EricJ. There's nothing wrong with it, however I want to be able to log my information, there's an attachment to this program that auto git pushes, so I'm trying to do this: create backup => git push for production => log backup name + git push ID..

Comment: @EricJ. However it is a good idea, could you post it as an answer with an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly want to make a backup of a git archive I suggest you call git's own function for that.

```
git copy source-path target-path
```

This way you get a bare repo clone that will take less space and the copy is as fast as it can be.

You restore by simply cloning from the backup.

Comment: Hmm, didn't know about this one. That could work, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic tree problem (like a binary tree). At some point you have to write recursion into your function, which is a function that calls itself. Something like:

```
public List<string> GetFiles(string folder)
{
    List<string> allFilesPaths = new List<string>();
    string[] allSubDirectories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories();
    for(int i = 0;i<allSubDirectories.Length; i++)
    {
       //you may need to format this path a bit but this is the magic of 
      //recursion, its calling itself!
       List<string> subfiles = GetFiles(folder + allSubDirectories[i]); 
       allFilesPaths.AddRange(subfiles);
    }
    string[] allFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder);
    //You may need to append the entire path onto each file if you want
    allFilesPaths.AddRange(allFiles);
    return allFilesPaths;
}
Main()
{
   string RootDirectoryPath = "...";
   List<string> allFilesPaths = GetFiles(RootDirectoryPath );
   //copy each file one by one
}
```

Comment: This seems like to could kind of kill the process speed a bit, however I do like this, and see how it could work wonders